# Can I access In-memory tables with more than one thread (MySQL & Java)?

Tags: java, mysql, database, multithreading, in-memory

I have an time-critical JAVA application which uses an in-memory database (in my case MySQL) to answer queries.

In order to speed the process up, I thought about using multiple threads (so that multiple processors can work simultaniously). So my first question would be if in-memory tables can be run faster with a multi-threaded environment.

If the answer to this first question is yes, then I need some advice how to do this. I experimented with 2 approaches:

1. I gave all threads the same jdbc instance. There were no performance increases with this tactic.
2. I tried to create new instances for each thread and tried to connect it to my previously created database:

   `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
   this.executeQuery("USE myDatabase");`

With this second version I get an error saying:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'rockit'

In an one thread environment there is no error at this point.

Comment: I thought "in memory databases" are in the memory of the process. Does MySQL support running as an embedded library?

Comment: This is exactly my question ;-).

Comment: I would be very surprised if it did. AFAIK the databases you can easily embed in Java are written in Java.